# Метод XML.exist() в SQL запросе не работает корректно с переменными

Tags: sql-server, xml

Основная задача заключалась в переносе логики поиска нужных XML файлов по заданному со стороны пользователя XPath. Для этого использовал приведение хранимых XML из text типа в XML и готовые из коробки методы работы с XML. В моем случае это метод exist. С ним возникла проблема - он не работает с SQL переменными. Так как, в моем случае, я отправляю запрос на сторону БД и передаю в нем параметры, где XPath задается динамически, я могу использовать только значение данной переменной.
Пример кода, когда переменная в exist не работает и равенство с 1 всегда верно для всех XML и возвращает true, что выгружает абсолютно все записи, а не только те, которые удовлетворяют XPath:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1000) ord.TrackingID, ord.DateCreate, ord.OrderType, ord.Error_Description, ord.Response, ord.Request
                    FROM FilteredByXPath AS ord
                    WHERE (ord.Response.exist(''sql:variable("@XPath")'') = 1) OR (ord.Request.exist(''sql:variable("@XPath")'') = 1)',
                    N'@TrackingID nvarchar(4000),@ShowAutotestCases bit,@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@InputOrderSource nvarchar(1),@Agency int, @XPath nvarchar(max)',
                    @TrackingID=NULL,@ShowAutotestCases=0,@DateFrom='1753-01-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997',@InputOrderSource=N'%',@Agency=0, @XPath=N'//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'
```

Но если мы напрямую попробуем вставить выражение из переменной @XPath в качестве аргумента метода exist, то получим корректную выборку.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1000) ord.TrackingID, ord.DateCreate, ord.OrderType, ord.Error_Description, ord.Response, ord.Request
                    FROM FilteredByXPath AS ord
                    WHERE (ord.Response.exist(''//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'') = 1) OR (ord.Request.exist(''//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'') = 1)',
                    N'@TrackingID nvarchar(4000),@ShowAutotestCases bit,@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@InputOrderSource nvarchar(1),@Agency int, @XPath nvarchar(max)',
                    @TrackingID=NULL,@ShowAutotestCases=0,@DateFrom='1753-01-01 00:00:00',@DateTo='9999-12-31 23:59:59.997',@InputOrderSource=N'%',@Agency=0, @XPath=N'//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]'
```

Возможно какая-то проблема при использовании sql:variable метода или что-то ещё. Буду признателен за полезные комментарии и советы.

Comment: `"@XPath"` точно нужно в кавычках?

Comment: @DrMcSheen Если не ошибаюсь,то да. В примерах выделяют двойными. Я пробовал без них, с одинарными - в этих случаях не выполняется и бросает ошибку по синтаксису выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подготовить оператор SQL и использовать функцию `QUOTENAME()` для обработки выражения XPath. И только после этого используйте `sp_executesql`.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @XPath NVARCHAR(100) = N'//*[text() = "10:33:34.9375000-05:00"]';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1024) = N'SELECT TOP(1000) ord.TrackingID, ord.DateCreate, ord.OrderType, ord.Error_Description, ord.Response, ord.Request
                    FROM FilteredByXPath AS ord
                    WHERE (ord.Response.exist(' + QUOTENAME(@Xpath,CHAR(39)) + ') = 1) OR (ord.Request.exist(' + QUOTENAME(@Xpath,CHAR(39)) + ') = 1)';

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, ...
```